# How to convert openssl_encrypt raw output to binary string?

Tags: php, radix

I am encrypting some numbers with `openssl_encrypt`, example:

```
<?php

$input = 123;
$binary = decbin($input);

echo $binary; // outputs: 1111011

$cipher = 'aes-128-ecb';
$key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);

$encodedRaw = openssl_encrypt($binary, $cipher, $key, true);

echo $encodedRaw; // outputs: D�f�e↓v�ne��|۵�
```

Now, since everything is a number, and encodedRaw is just some binary stream (which translates to some weird random-ish -like characters) I tried to convert that back into binary (`01`) format.

```
$binary2 = bindec($encodedRaw);

echo $binary2; // outputs: 0
```

It seems the bindec() fails and returns false, which is magically converted by PHP to `0`. To confirm this I made a loop with 20 random $inputs, and they all returned `0` in the last step.

### How to convert `openssl_encrypt` output to binary string (that consists of 0's and 1's)?

Comment: 1) `echo false` outputs nothing, `0` is already something. 2) See [the manual](http://php.net/bindec) for what `bindec` expects; it does not in fact deal with raw binary strings.

Comment: how to convert raw binary string to binary string then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`decbin` returns a string of '0' and '1' charcters.
`bindec` does the opposite. It expects a string of  '0' and '1' charcters.

It has nothing to do with binary data returned by `openssl_encrypt`.

If you like to print `$encodedRaw` in human-readable  form, you can use [unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php), e.g. to return a hex string:

```
var_dump(unpack('h*', $encodedRaw));
```

To print a string similar to `bindec` output you can do something like this:

```
$binStr = "";
foreach(str_split(unpack('h*', $encodedRaw)[1]) as $v) {
    $binStr .= decbin(hexdec($v));
}
echo $binStr;
```

Comment: It seems the `foreach` loop produces diffrent results than `gmp_strval` with base 2 argument. Yours is probably the wrong one. Anyways, you got me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: Well, I don't have `gmp` handy, but it seems it works with number only, not sure how it works with arbitrary binary data. Also it is important to read the documentation I pointed to. e.g. using `unpack('H*'...)` you get a binary string with high and low octets swapped.

Answer (score 0):

### Appendix to Alex's anwser

- `$hex = unpack('h*', $cipherText)[1]` converts raw binary to hex
- `$cipherText = pack('h*', $hex)` converts hex string to raw binary

While `dexhex` and `hexdec` do the decimal <-> hex conversion, in my case they failed, becouse I was working with huge numbers.

Therefore I recommend useing GMP extension:

- `$gmp = gmp_init($hex, 16);` hex to GMP, then:
- `$dec = gmp_strval($gmp, 10);` GMP number to base 10 number STRING representation
- `$bin = gmp_strval($gmp, 2);` GMP number to base 2 number STRING representation